# SQL joining tables and having where clause from the joined table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

Currently not working...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLICKHISTORY
INNER JOIN EDSC ON CLICKHISTORY.SOURCEID = EDSC.SOURCEID 
WHERE EDSC.DOMAIN='SCMDomain';
```

Currently this returns Count = 0, and in words I want to merge two tables on the sourceID's and then filter out all data so we are only left with EDSC.DOMAIN= 'SCMDomain.

EDSC and CLICKHISTORY are the two tables. Thanks

Comment: You are doing what you are saying "in words", and that filter returns 0 rows

Comment: that should retain data where the EDSC.DOMAIN = 'SCMDomain', which should in the db is a nonzero value.

Comment: in that table may have some rows, but there is no match on the other table

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  The quotes look odd `WHERE EDSC.DOMAIN='SCMDomain'";`

Comment: oracle server that i am writing in java, so the query is  a string, hence the outer quote

Comment: The goal would be to join the two tables on SourceID and then filter out all values where the domain, currently on EDSC table is not 'SCMDomain'

Comment: That's what you're doing. So if there are no rows returned, it's likely that your query is doing exactly what you want, but your data is not what you expect. Can you show us example rows from your `EDSC` and `CLICKHISTORY` tables where you think `EDSC.DOMAIN` is 'SCMDomain' and that row links on `SOURCEID` to a row in `CLICKHISTORY`? Basically, pick a single result you'd expect to be COUNTed and work back from there to show us the rows in the tables that would produce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way of writing it without the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CLICKHISTORY
WHERE CLICKHISTORY.SOURCEID IN (
    SELECT EDSC.SOURCEID
    FROM EDSC
    WHERE EDSC.DOMAIN = 'SCMDomain')
```

Comment: Though this might be what op wants, the queries are not necessarily equivalent